# OnChange and Click simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have the following scenario:

Two 'Controls' like this:

```
<span class="search-select">
    <select id="Item_TBUID" name="ViewModel.SearchTbuid">
        <option value="" style="display: block;" selected="selected">ALL</option>
    </select>
    <input class="textfield" id="textfield_SearchTbuid" name="textfield.SearchTbuid" type="text" value="" />
</span>
```

The 'Control' is involved in a couple of events.

- `input.textfield` on `focusout` triggers the select's `change` event (via trigger).
- The select's `change` event triggers an ajax call to change the second Control's options (simply put, cascading dropdowns).

When I type something into the input (filtering the options of the first Control's select) and then immediately click on the second Control's dropdown (the one cascading) it partially loads the new data. It will fully load the new data (from ajax call) if I simply lose focus of the select and click it again.

I know the following isn't super useful code but I don't want to paste a bunch of code when 90% of it is irrelevant since I'm asking about events, their order, etc.

```
/* Applies the SearchSelect plugin to all controls 
 *  which filters the select's options and triggers the
 *  select's change event when the textfield loses focus.
 */
$(".search-select").SearchSelect();

/* Applies cascading event to the select element.
 * Which makes an ajax call for the new options.
 *  The success event of the ajax call then adds the options
 *      to the second control's select.
 */
cascade(RetailerCostZone);
```

**Question**: How can I tell the select's click event that displays the options to wait on the AJAX call to finish fully?

Comment: Use a callback function

Comment: Is there a method in particular you recommend? I realized when you mentioned callback that I had forgotten about the ajax on complete function so I added a disabled attr and removed it in the complete callback but now it causes you to have to click the dropdown twice. So it's more of a treatment that a cure. Not sure how to handle it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered putting the ajax call on the onclick or onfocus of the other control, with the success triggering its normal behavior?  So that every time you focus on it it will get the correct data first?

Also, since the data in the second control is dependent on that of the first, maybe you could just have a submit button with the first control that loads the options for the second.

Comment: The onClick comment is a good point. For now I think I'm going to  cache what's in the textfield and if it's not different don't update and that should kill 90% of the problem behavior. If it becomes a problem for the users I'll convert it to the onClick solution.